# How to Implement Global Ros Variables

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin, environment-variables

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a stationary pick-and-place type robot. I have created a large catkin workspace for a project that uses various packages. Currently, when I want to change certain variables in my project (like camera location), I need to open multiple packages and edit files individually. I want to streamline the project by creating a configuration file that holds global variables for the entire workspace (so they only need to be edited in one place).

Is this possible to do in ROS? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363337/how-to-implement-global-ros-variables/) by [fruitbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/60887/fruitbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2020-10-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-10-13**:\

> Currently, when I want to change certain variables in my project (like camera location), I need to open multiple packages and edit files individually

are you not using TF?

---

Edit: reason I ask this and don't directly address your question is I'm wondering whether this is an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info). If you could give a few more examples of the sort of data you're looking to share, perhaps we can give better answers.

**Comment by [fruitbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/60887/fruitbot/) on 2020-10-13**:
Yes I am using TF. I realize I wasn't clear in my original question. For each variable I want to change, there is only ONE corresponding file I need to edit. When my physical set up changes, say I set up the robot in a new area, I need to edit quite variables, and  therefore quite a few files. In addition to camera location, there are multiple bins that the arm sorts items in to, whose position and size may change. Workspace area may change size. Most of the edits take place in my main urdf, but a couple are in other places. Perhaps I should edit my urdfs so all the configurable information is my main urdf?

The reason I was hoping to make some sort of global configuration file is because other people will be setting up my project and I want to make configuration as easy and straight forward as possible.

This is the first time I've heard of the xy problem, what a handy idea!

**Comment by [fruitbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/60887/fruitbot/) on 2020-10-13**:
Edit: IP address for robotic arm is another variable, one that is not urdf related. Another is camera path location (eg. /dev/video0, /dev/video1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given the types of data you mention, I would suggest to use the ROS parameter server for this.

The `roslaunch` [rosparam tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam) in combination with `.yaml` files makes for a very convenient way to store and load settings of a ROS application. Example:

```
camera:
  device: /dev/video0
robot:
  ip_address: 1.2.3.4
workspace:
  area: [0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4]
bins:
 - id: 1
   area: [0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4]
 - id: 4
   ...
```

etc.

Whether you load those parameters in the private namespace of nodes, or put them in a separate namespace and then have nodes load "their section" from that namespace would be a design decision only you can make (the former would reduce coupling though, so might perhaps be a better approach).

One thing I'm still wondering about: if you have to edit multiple files "when things change", this may be an indication of a violation of separation of concerns (ie: too many nodes/classes/functions need to be aware of various details to be able to do their work). It may be good to investigate whether all those entities actually *need* all that information, or whether they could get it from somewhere else (as part of a service request coming in, fi).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fruitbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/60887/fruitbot/) on 2020-10-14**:
The ROS parameter server looks like the tool I need. I will continue to look into it.

Your concern about "separation of concerns" may be valid. This project is my first experience with ROS, so I will keep an eye out for that as I and clean things up.

Thanks for your help!